# Convergence test of the following improper integral $\int_0^\infty \frac {e^{-1/x}-1} {\ x^{2/3}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I've been trying for a couple of hours to prove the convergence of the following integral: $$\int_0^\infty \frac {e^{-1/x}-1} {\ x^{2/3}}dx$$
Eventually I understood from Wolfram-Alpha that the integral converges to $\Gamma(-1/3)$ and it makes sense because by substitution $t=1/x $ I get the following integral: $$\int_0^\infty \frac {e^{-t}-1} {\ t^{4/3}}dt$$ And it's pretty close to $\Gamma(-1/3)$ except for the $-1$ that bothers me. What have I done wrong until this point? And how can I prove it? Thank you.

Comment: There is a missing minus somewhere

Comment: Actually i get: $$-\int_\infty^0 \frac {e^{-t}-1} {\ t^{4/3}}dt = \int_0^\infty \frac {e^{-t}-1} {\ t^{4/3}}dt$$ Anything done wrong here? As long as I see no minus missing.

Comment: @EvgenyA. Nothing wrong.  Your substitution is fine.

Comment: @EvgenyA. What's also weird is if you put $$\int_0^{\infty}t^{-\frac{4}{3}}e^{-t}\, dt$$ into Wolfram Alpha it says it does not converge.  But, that is the definition of $\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)$.

Comment: Yeah I've noticed that too, it's really strange that the original one converges but after the substitution it's seems like something goes wrong.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126: That integral converges only when the exponent is greater then $-1$.

Comment: @EvgenyA. As Lucian pointed out, and I forgot, the definition of Gamma as $$\Gamma(x)=\int_0^{\infty}t^{x-1}e^{-t}\, dt$$ only works for $x>0$.  The analytical continuation for $x<0$ has a different definition.

Comment: @EvgenyA. Here is an explanation.  We let $$I(k)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-kx}-1}{x^{\frac{4}{3}}}\, dx.$$  Then $I$ is a function of $k$.  So, $$I'(k)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{d}{dk}\frac{e^{-kx}-1}{x^{\frac{4}{3}}}\,dx=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{-xe^{-kx}}{x^\frac{4}{3}}\,dx$$ Canceling powers of $x$ gives us $$I'(k)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{-e^{-kx}}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\,dx$$  Now you can do a substitution for $u=kx$ and get the integral $$I'(k)=-\frac{1}{k^{\frac{2}{3}}}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-u}}{u^\frac{1}{3}}\, du.$$

Comment: This is $$I'(k)=-\frac{1}{k^{\frac{2}{3}}}\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right).$$  Now integrate with respect to $k$: $$I(k)=\int I'(k)\, dk=-3k^\frac{1}{3}\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right).$$  Plug in $k=1$ and use the property of $Gamma$ that says $\Gamma(1+t)=t\Gamma(t)$ to get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $I(k)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-kx}-1}{x^n}~dx$. Now, evaluate $I'(k)$ by differentiating under the integral sign. Then integrate that expression, and let $k=1$.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't really understand how to continue from here, suppose I can differentiate under the integral sign(Should the function sequence inside converge uniformly so I can do that?) and what do I integrate after? I'(k)? I'm studying calculus right now and I haven't encountered such methods yet, so it will be very helpful if you'll provide some additional details. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. $I(k)=\displaystyle\int I'(k)~dk.~$ But $I'(k)$ has such a simple expression in terms of *k*...

Comment: Sorry but I just don't get how it helps me here.. You mean something like that $I(k)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-kx}-1}{x^n}~dx=\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} -k\frac{e^{-kx}}{x^n}~dx = I'(k)$ ? I guess it's without the double integral but why is this even true then? $I(k)$ is a sequence of integrals or I completely misunderstood you hint?

Comment: You're supposed to differentiate with regard to *k*... And there aren't any limits of integration on $\displaystyle\int I'(k)~dk$.

Comment: @Lucian If $n=\dfrac{4}{3}$, don't you end up with $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-kx}}{x^{\frac{4}{3}}}\, dx,$$ which doesn't exist?

Comment: No, @JoeJohnson126. Again: We differentiate with regard to *k*...

Comment: @Lucian Yes, and we get $$I'(k)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{-e^{-kx}}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\, dx.$$ But, when we integrate with respect to $k$, the power on the $x$ goes back up.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126: You're half-way there... Doesn't that integral look familiar ? :-$)$

Comment: @Lucian Ah, if I do a $u$-substitution, I get $$I'(k)=-3k^{\frac{1}{3}}\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$$ which converts to $\Gamma\left(-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)$ when $k=1$.  Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126: Yes, exactly. And to answer your previous question, when we integrate back, we have to choose an appropriate constant of integration. In that case, that constant $($with regard to $k)$ would have been $-\dfrac1{x^n}$. Here, the constant can be determined from the fact that $I(0)=0$.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126:I got really confused.. can you maybe explain what Lucian meant with more steps?